# FileZilla sees fewer files than File Manager?

Tags: web-hosting, ftp

I am trying to download a directory with a large amount of files (6,003 to be exact) all PNGs.

When I download them via FTP using FileZilla I only get 4,308 files. This is the same whilst browsing the directory (The files are in alphabetical order and  stop at 'm'). However, if I view the same directory and files in CPanel's File Manager I can see them all.

Would anyone know why this is happening and how best to fix it? Is there some limit FileZilla has and can it be adjusted?

(This is on FileZilla 3.5.3 on a Windows 7 computer, from a LAMP stack shared host).

EDIT: College just tried Cyber Duck on his Mac - same issue occurred.

Comment: I can tell you that I used my FTP to delete some debug files on my site- there was a m@j0r cr@p l0@d of them!! My FTP client did something very strange. It would only show a certain number of the debug files at a time, and still show the rest of the other files within that directory. As I deleted about a thousand files at a shot, it would refresh with the same number, but not all, of the debug files and again the other files within that directory. This continued as I deleted the files and was down to just a few debug files. This happened more than once over a span of days and weeks. Strange.

Comment: @closetnoc were you using FileZilla? Might just be a bug with that client

Comment: I was using another WS-FTP Pro and an old copy to boot. There may be a limit in FTP but I would suspect that it would be on the server side. Not sure why I think that- I just do. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there's better ways of downloading or viewing files stored on your server. Generally FTP is old, slow and unreliable compared to other methods.

If you have CPANEL you should really be using SFTP or the File manager. Using the file manager you can simply compress the folder meaning you don't have to download 6,003 files. FTP/SFTP is limited to one a request at a time unless you SFTP client supports mulch-threading, but even so I still recommend the file compression route using either SSH or the file manager. For security reasons I recommend you disable FTP all together and just use SFTP, SSH or the file manager.

If you still would like to use FTP or just wondering why only a portion of results are being displayed, its likely because your listing method is restricted. You can increase the listing method by editing your FTP config, if using PureFTPD you need to increase `LimitRecursion`.

1. Login to server using SSH
2. Edit the pure-ftpd.conf generally found in `/etc`
3. Change `LimitRecursion 2000 8` to something like `LimitRecursion
   10000 8`
4. Restart service using `service pure-ftpd restart`